# Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined Nativescript Angular

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have face the issue in nativescript angular. I'm using the Latest Nativescript(6.1.1) coremodules, android, ios versions 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.1 respectively. I also try in older version that also return the same error.

Before, My Nativescript version was 5.3.4 and run using Bundle Workflow.

```
 /Users/Myapp/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:244
                throw err;
                ^

TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__extends (/Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:65:9)
    at /Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:115:17
    at /Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:314:6
    at /Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/template.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (/Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (/Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at /Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/transform.js:20:22
    at /Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/transform.js:10:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/indexer/src/transform.js:16:3)
    at Module._compile (/Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (/Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at /Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/program.js:31:23
    at /Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/program.js:10:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtsc/program.js:16:3)
    at Module._compile (/Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (/Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at /Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:27:21
    at /Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:10:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/deemsys/Documents/FoodApp_New/trunk/User/FoodCourt/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:16:3)
```

Package.json

````
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "nativescript-accordion": "^6.0.0-beta.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "8.0.2",
    "nativescript-checkbox": "^3.0.3",
    "nativescript-drop-down": "^4.0.1",
    "nativescript-feedback": "^1.3.9",
    "nativescript-geolocation": "5.1.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.3.0",
    "nativescript-loading-indicator": "^2.4.0",
    "nativescript-ng-ripple": "^2.0.1",
    "nativescript-phone": "^1.4.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "9.0.2",
    "nativescript-ratings": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "7.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.1.1",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.4.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "8.2.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.2.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "6.0.1",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  }
```
````

Comment: Are you seeing this issue only after upgrade, specifically after webpack migration? Did you update your webpack dependencies & config too as part of upgrade.

Comment: No, I face the Issue before upgrade. After Upgrade I also try the command node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs .    Yes, I update the webpack dependencies

Comment: I was update here package.json content

Comment: Can you share a GitHub sample where the issue can be reproduced

Comment: I forgot to update angular dependencies now i am able to build the application.but how to solve the issue 'UILaunchImages' has been deprecated, use launch storyboards instead. (in target 'FoodCourt' from project 'FoodCourt' Xcode 11

Comment: When using bundle, css was not applied to the whole application.

Comment: I think you should take one at a time, you can't use one single thread to discuss various issue. Debug on your end, when you don't find a solution for something you should raise a thread with all the details. Besides, Splash / Launch Images were replaced with StoryBoard long back, you may get a sample from a default template generated by CLI, for example [this one here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-app-templates/blob/master/packages/template-master-detail-ts/app/App_Resources/iOS/LaunchScreen.storyboard)